# How to upload a file using Multer in a specific directory defined by the frontend in vuejs

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, multer

I want to upload a file using Multer in a specific directory in my NodeJs app defined by the frontend in vuejs.

It is my first application with multer

The backend code is :

```
...
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        //req.body.idUser is undefined here
        let destinationPath = path.join("upload_file", req.body.idUser);
        if (!fs.existsSync(destinationPath)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(destinationPath);
        }
        cb(null, destinationPath);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        let newFileName = Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
        cb(null, newFileName);
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post(
    "/file/add",
    upload.fields([{ name: "newfile" }, { name: "idUser" }]),
    (req, res) => {
        res.json({
            response: "file uploaded",
        });
    },
);
...
```

And the frontend code is :

```
...
async sendDocument(event){
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    const form = new FormData()
    form.append("newfile", file, file.name)
    form.append("idUser", this.getIdUser)
    const opts =
    {
        method: "POST",
        body: form,
    }
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/file/add";
    try{
        await fetch(url, opts)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res)
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
},
...
```

I tried to debug step by step with console.log to check why `req.body.idUser` is not defined in `storage` and I need it to complete the destinationPath

If I replace `req.body.idUser` by static value like `"toto"`, all work fine

In front, `this.getIdUser` is working fine. And `req.body.idUser` is working in `app.post`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try appending the ID to the form first:

```
const form = new FormData()
form.append("idUser", this.getIdUser)
form.append("newfile", file, file.name)
```

Comment: That's right ! You are my savior ^^